Particular values of multiple zeta functions of even weight
I'm new to the fascinating field of multiple zeta values.
I just want to know if there are known evaluations for $\zeta(6,2)$ or $\zeta(9,3)$ or other particular case when the weight of the multiple zeta value is even ?
Thanks in advance.
